# How to simplify multiple if-else-if statements in c++

Tags: c++, control-flow

Suppose I have four functions for four cases:

```
void ac() {
 //do something
}
void ad() {
 //do something
}
void bc() {
 //do something
}
void bd() {
 //do something
}

void f(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
    if(a and c) {
        ac();
    }
    else if(a and d) {
        ad();
    }
    else if(b and c) {
        bc();
    }
    else if(b and d){
        bd();
    }
    else {
            throw 1;
    }
}
```

For the 2 by 2 situation it's quite simple, but in more complex situations, 
    this can get very tedious. Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: How familiar are you with things like finite state machines?

Comment: What's a concrete situation where you would need such a construct?

Comment: There's a flaw in your logic: You don't check `b` and `d`, instead you unconditionally call `bd` when no other case is true. At least I *assume* it's a flaw, considering the logic for the other functions.

Comment: I think this question is too broad, could you be more specific?

Comment: You don't need to check `a` (or `b`) twice. Instead I would have nested `if` (of `switch`) statements. Yes, it can be a lot to write, but it will also be very easy to read and understand what's happening (which I consider more important in the long run).

Answer (score 9):

```
#define A 0x1
#define B 0x2
#define C 0x4
#define D 0x8

void f(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
    int mask = 0;
    if( a ) mask |= A;
    if( b ) mask |= B;
    if( c ) mask |= C;
    if( d ) mask |= D;
    // Alternative is to use mask as a subscript in an array of function pointers.
    switch( mask ) {
    case A|C: ac(); break;
    case A|D: ad(); break;
    case B|C: bc(); break;
    default: bd(); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RontogiannisAristofanis Mmm. I couldn't accept it as "more concise". So... I created a compiletime solution based on `constexpr` that will calculate the switch value and case values for up to 64 booleans on the fly o.O (see my answer)

Comment: Uh, that's not equivalent to the OP's code, if all the args are true, he calls ac().

Answer (score 3):

Brian's answer tempted me. I had a very hard time calling this "more concise". So I figured, I should be able to arrive at something like:

```
void f(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
    switch(combine(a, b, c, d))
    {
        case combine(1,0,1,0): ac(); break;
        case combine(1,0,0,1): ad(); break;
        case combine(0,1,1,0): bc(); break;
        default: bd(); break;
    }
}
```

And, with the magic of `constexpr` it can be done: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f29f8204b95aef6)**

Demo program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>

namespace detail
{
    // a little overkill to have a functor here too, but it's a good habit™
    template <typename T = uintmax_t>
    struct to_bitmask_f
    {
        template <typename... Flags> struct result { typedef T type; };

        template <typename... Flags>
            typename result<Flags...>::type
            constexpr operator()(Flags... flags) const {
                static_assert(sizeof...(Flags) < std::numeric_limits<uintmax_t>::digits, "Too many flags for integral representation)");
                return impl(flags...);
            }

    private:
        constexpr static inline T impl() { return {}; }
        template <typename... Flags>
            constexpr static inline T impl(bool b, Flags... more) { 
            return (b?1:0) + (impl(more...) << (T(1)));
        }
    };
}

template <typename T = uintmax_t, typename... Flags>
    constexpr T combine(Flags... flags)
{
    return detail::to_bitmask_f<T>()(flags...);
}

void ac() { std::cout << "ac\n"; }
void ad() { std::cout << "ad\n"; }
void bc() { std::cout << "bc\n"; }
void bd() { std::cout << "bd\n"; }

void f(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
    switch(combine(a, b, c, d))
    {
        case combine(1,0,1,0): ac(); break;
        case combine(1,0,0,1): ad(); break;
        case combine(0,1,1,0): bc(); break;
        default: bd(); break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    f(1,0,1,0);
    f(1,0,0,1);
    f(0,1,1,0);
    f(0,1,0,1);
    // others:
    f(0,1,1,1);
    f(1,1,1,1);
    f(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Printing out:

```
ac
ad
bc
bd
bd
bd
bd
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a 3 dimensional function pointer array?

```
const void (*func[2][2][2][2]) = { { { {allFalse, aFalseBFalseCFalseDTrue}, {AllButCFalse, AllButCandDFalse}... } } };
void f(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
    func[a][b][c][d]();
}
```

You could combine this with masking like @brianbeuning used:

```
const void (*func[1 << 4]);
void initArray() {
    func[0] = allFalse;
    func[1 << 0] = allFalseButD;
    func[1 << 1] = allFalseButC;
    func[1 << 0 | 1 << 2] = DandCTrue;
    // ...
}

void f(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
    func[a << 3 | b << 2 | c << 1 | d << 0]();
}
```

Comment: When I see "3D" and "function pointer", *simpler* isn't the first word that comes to mind.

Comment: @DaoWen :)  but it _looks_ simple... except the `const void (*func[2][2][2])`. It is compact however.

Comment: It looks simple? Assuming you'd fill in for the `...` it would appear to me that you get a long list of "arbitrary" function pointer initializers, which are very hard to trace to the particular combination they are wired to. Also, it's very easy to miss elements and you'll silently be invoking through null pointers. I'd say this is just a bad idea.